# Assumption about angular velocity

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, angular-velocity

Can you assume that an object moving counterclockwise has positive angular velocity and any torque that is pushing the object counterclockwise is positive? And vice versa for clockwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but it is the common assumption that we follow for vector quantities like Angular velocity, angular momentum, torque for the purpose of analysis of rotation i.e. static or dynamic equilibrium.

Suppose that a body is subjected to two forces which try to rotate it in opposite directions then we have to follow one assumption to take either clockwise or anticlockwise torques positive to apply the Newton's second law for rotation
$$T_{net}=I\frac{d\omega}{dt}$$ $$\vec T=I\frac{d\vec\omega}{dt}$$
here the direction of angular velocity $\vec \omega$ depends on the direction of net applied torque $\vec T$. The direction of applied torque $\vec T$ can be taken positive in anticlockwise or clockwise. But the most common assumption is that $\vec \omega$ & $\vec T$ are positive in anticlockwise direction

Comment: No torque may be in opposite direction of angular velocity as well.

Comment: Please correct the equations as well.

Comment: @Sarcasm Thanks for spotting the error. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The direction and magnitude of angular velocity is governed by this equation 
$$\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}×\vec{r}$$

Angular velocity and torque are related to each other by this equation

$$\vec{T}=I\frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the rotation of an object depends on your location relative to the object.  When viewed from space above the north pole, the earth rotates counterclockwise.  Viewed from the south, its CW.  A resultant torque vector (direction defined by a right-hand-rule) determines the direction of an angular acceleration vector.